# What is <permission-tree> in android manifest ? How to make use of this?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

Using "permission" and "uses-permission" tags we can give and access permissions.
Then why we need "permission-tree", In which way it is useful?

Answer (score 7):

`permission-tree` allows an application to declare a namespace of permissions, in which it can dynamically at runtime define new permissions.  This is used example, by google's service APIs to have a namespace for individual permissions to each google service that it discovers at runtime.

Comment: Thanks StinePike, from your answer what i understood is we can add a set of permission to a tree with some name space. but assume if are having application A with permission-tree and name space is "com.example.permissiontree.xxx" then how other application can use this.

Answer (score 1):

permission-tree is namespace and used for adding new permissions at run time. If you want to add new permissions then that should be defined earlier or used by any other application previously with same key.
This feature is **back-> forward** means you can use for your comfort (if you don't want to give set of permission again).